# My android app can download but doesnt appear in my downloaded apps

Tags: android, google-play, publish

My new android app can download from the playstore but doesn't appear in my downloaded apps. When i download it from the play store usually there is an option to 'open' the app aswell as 'uninstall', only the uninstall button is visible. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXXuU.png notice the missing open button)

here's the my manifest, there were no errors during all the tests i ran.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jackattackapps.bigl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconimage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.jackattackapps.bigl.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.jackattackapps.bigl.Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the activity that is supposed to load on the start of the application.

```
package com.jackattackapps.bigl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{

                MediaPlayer ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splashscreen.this, R.raw.splashsound);
                ourSong.start();
                sleep(2300);

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();

}
```

}

if more information is needed just comment, help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Launcher activity should have this `Intent Filter`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yess sir that does it - your my hero for the week thanks a ton